# displaying a full link using NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c

Simple question, new to iOS and Objective-C, not understand why it's not doing the full link.

```
 NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@", setCourseNumber, "?json=True");
```

output: http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/32-2400

Not going to go into what the coursenumber is, no point, the question is that my output is not including the "?json=True" part of the link. I know it must be something small that I am not including, I just am new to Objective-C and can't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need a another %@ for the last string.  NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@/%@", setCourseNumber, "?json=True");

Comment: Ah I tried to add another %@ (without the extra /, did not think of that) and it gave me an error. Thank you.

Comment: Actually when I try that I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1)

Comment: Or just: `NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@?json=True", setCourseNumber);`

Comment: @Alladinian did not know I can do that, that works, thank you sir.

Comment: Also, please notice that the last param in your NSLog is not a valid string literal.  It needs a leading @ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Logan beat me too it.

[Here's some more information from Apple's documentation on formatting string objects.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

[Here's a list of string formats.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) Things like %@, %d, etc.

Comment: Quick question, instead of NSLog, how would I go about putting into a string, and then to debug I would like to put it into a NSLog.     NSString * JSONLink = (@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@?json=True", setCourseNumber);
    NSLog(JSONLink); for instance is not working. Doesn't like that I just have "JSONLink" in a NSLog, I'm guessing I need some sort of % but after reading some documentation, that only refers to integers.

Comment: When I try @"%@" it only returns the number and not the entire string I declared.

Comment: @jjgamedev You'll need to do something like this: NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A string: %@", @"string"]; Then do NSLog(string1);

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@", setCourseNumber, "?json=True");
```

Could be this:

```
NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@?json=True", setCourseNumber);
```

Comment: Will check answer when time allows me to, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have two arguments, but using only one:

```
NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@", setCourseNumber, "?json=True");
```

`setCourseNumber` is first attribute - `%@`
`"?json=True"` is second attribute - ? 
So you can modify it like this:

```
NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@%@", setCourseNumber, "?json=True")
```

Or use

```
NSLog(@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/%@?json=True", setCourseNumber)
```

No matter, where argument is situated - in the middle or in the end.